# How to make ToUpperCase Working in this case

Tags: angularjs

I have a text Input field and i dont want user to allow the words already present (Case inSensitiviness) under tickts JSON

I have tried using

```
var value = val.toUpperCase();
```

Exception under console

```
VM226 angular.js:6173 TypeError: Cannot read property 'toUpperCase' of undefined
    at Child.$scope.checkQuestions (VM227:78)
    at Object.get (VM226 angular.js:6801)
    at Object.$digest (VM226 angular.js:8563)
    at Object.$apply (VM226 angular.js:8771)
    at VM226 angular.js:986
    at Object.invoke (VM226 angular.js:2873)
    at resumeBootstrapInternal (VM226 angular.js:984)
    at bootstrap (VM226 angular.js:998)
    at angularInit (VM226 angular.js:959)
    at VM226 angular.js:16310
```

My Code:

```
  var myapp = angular.module('myapp', []);
    myapp.controller('FirstCtrl', function($scope)
    {
        $scope.$watch('vm.status.name', function(val)
        {
                var myarray = [];
                for (var i = 0; i < $scope.tickets.length; i++)
                {
                        var name = $scope.tickets[i].name.toUpperCase();

                        myarray.push(name);
                }
                $scope.checkQuestions = function()
                {
                    //var value = val.toUpperCase();
                        if (myarray.indexOf(val) !== -1)
                        {
                                return true;
                        }
                        else
                        {
                                return false;
                        }
                };
        });
    });
```

This is my fiddle

Try Entering Open and Closed under the text input

http://jsfiddle.net/9fR23/424/

Comment: val seems undefined

Comment: In the first digest cycle there isn't a `vm.status.name` yet, so it will be undefined

Comment: You can capitalize when you bind on the view https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/filter/uppercase

Comment: or may be with CSS  ' text-transform : uppercase '

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think, there is no need to add watch to input text value.
You can just initialize `myarray` outside.

and you can create separate method for `checkQuestions` functionality.

like:

```
$scope.myarray = //add code to initialize this

$scope.checkQuestions = function()
{
     if (myarray.indexOf(vm.status.name.toUpperCase()) !== -1)
      {
            //do something.
      }
      else
      {
           //do other thing
       }
};
```

Answer (score 1):

Looks like your variable `val` is undefined.

Comment: thanks a lot , is there anyway i can avoid creating a myarray and do it more professionally ?

Answer (score 0):

try to add `var v = val;` inside `$scope.$watch` callback function and then use `v` like `var value = v.toUpperCase();`

Answer (score 0):

This fiddle seems to work for me(the save button is disabled when I enter "open".
http://jsfiddle.net/9fR23/426/

The main difference is replacing the `checkQuestions` function with a scope variable that is set in the `$watch` event function. I get the feeling that is probably what you are trying to do anyway. Your existing code defined the function in the `$watch` function and tried to use variables from it.